# In Shiny how to select one file and then run the App?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that reads from 3 excel files: "file_1.xlsx","file_2.xlsx" and "file_3.xlsx". But it only reads when I choose the options on the selectInput widget.

The `www`folder has a `data` folder that I inlcude this 3 files.

The code to read theses folder is:

```
file_1 <- read_xlsx('www/data/file_1.xlsx')
file_2 <- read_xlsx('www/data/file_2.xlsx')
file_3 <- read_xlsx('www/data/file_3.xlsx')

file_1_new <- file_1 %>% mutate(new_column = 'time series')
file_2_new <- file_1 %>% mutate(new_column = 'time series')
file_3_new <- file_1 %>% mutate(new_column = 'time series')
```

And this is my app file:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

file_1 <- read_xlsx('www/data/file_1.xlsx')
file_2 <- read_xlsx('www/data/file_2.xlsx')
file_3 <- read_xlsx('www/data/file_3.xlsx')

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = 'choices',label = "Files",choices = c('File1','File2','File3')),
  
  plotOutput('chart')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$choices,{
  
    if(input$choices == 'File1'){
      output$chart <- renderPlot({ggplot(file_1, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line(color = 'blue')})
    }else{
      if(input$choices == 'File2'){
        output$chart <-renderPlot({ggplot(file_2, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line(color = 'green')})
      }else{
        output$chart <-renderPlot({ggplot(file_3, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line(color = 'red')})
      }
    }
      
  }
  )

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In other words how can i make shiny reads the first file and then **AFTER** this run the app.

Comment: One possible example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027673/r-shiny-how-to-read-different-csv-file-based-of-user-input or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556329/using-drop-down-bottom-in-shiny-to-loaed-files-from-a-folder. Make the data source reactive so that you load the data in the server function, not before. You can have your dropdown box choose the file name and then read in the data from that file name into a reactive object.

Comment: @MrFlick If I need this reactive object to create others object in my R file? The file_1 object is an input for others objects in R. I would read file_1 as reactive and then I would need to "come back" to my R code and use this reactive object as input for others R object. It will work?

Comment: I changed the code. Once I read file_1 as reactive I need to create file_1new, file_2_new, file_3new using the file_* reactive objects.

Comment: Where is it suggested (in docs, in tutorials, etc) to nest `observe`/`reactive` blocks? I've never seen or done it in production, generally believing that it is a mistake in architecture. For your `output$chart` block, I suggest a _single_ `output$chart <- renderPlot(...)` block at the top-level within your `server` component, where inside you do something like `renderPlot({ dat <- switch(input$choices, File1=file_1, File2=file_2, file_3); ggplot(dat, ...); })`.

Comment: @r2evans I edited/fixed the code. I thinks my main problem is if I need to use this new reactive object  to computate others r objects I will need to inlcude my entire R code inside the server? making everything reactive?

Comment: Yes, in general, if your shiny app needs to react to different datasets, you have two options: (1) precompute everything for all datasets, this can be done outside of the `server` block; or (2) calculate on-the-fly, which allows you to adapt to dynamic (updated) data. This second part can only be done from within the `server` block, whether literal code blocks or functions defined (possibly elsewhere).

Comment: If you only ever use the data from one dataset at a time, you just need a single reactive object. You don't want one for each file. It's not clear to me why you are trying to read only one before the app starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: precompute all

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

allfiles <- c(File1="www/data/file_1.xlsx", File2="www/data/file_2.xlsx", File3="www/data/file_3.xlsx")
alldata <- lapply(files, function(f) readxl::read_xlsx(f) %>% mutate(new_column = "time series"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "choices", label = "Files", choices = names(allfiles)),
  plotOutput("chart")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mydata <- reactive({
    req(input$choices)
    alldata[[ input$choices ]]
  })
  output$chart <- renderPlot({
    req(mydata())
    col <- switch(isolate(input$choices),
                  File1 = "blue", File2 = "green",
                  File3 = "red", "black")
    ggplot(mydata(), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_line(color = col)
  })
}
```

### Option 2: reactively load and compute

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

allfiles <- c(File1="www/data/file_1.xlsx", File2="www/data/file_2.xlsx", File3="www/data/file_3.xlsx")
# alldata <- lapply(files, function(f) readxl::read_xlsx(f) %>% mutate(new_column = "time series"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "choices", label = "Files", choices = names(allfiles)),
  plotOutput("chart")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mydata <- reactive({
    req(input$choices)
    req(file.exists(allfiles[ input$choices ]))
    readxl::read_xlsx(allfiles[ input$choices ]) %>%
      mutate(new_column = "time series")
  })
  output$chart <- renderPlot({
    req(mydata())
    col <- switch(isolate(input$choices),
                  File1 = "blue", File2 = "green",
                  File3 = "red", "black")
    ggplot(mydata(), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_line(color = col)
  })
}
```

Depending on your calculation needs, I've seen utility in making `mydata` just the raw data (only `read_xlsx(..)`), and having another such as `mydata_upd <- eventReactive(mydata(), { mydata() %>% mutate(...) ... })`, where `output$chart` would then *only* depend on `mydata2()` (but something else might rely on `mydata()`). This separate use-case makes sense when this calculation filters/rearranges or somehow changes the data in a way that cannot be easily inferred from looking at `mydata2()`.

---

The `req` blocks could definitely be improved to use `validate`/`need`, doing a better job of informing the user if/when something is not right.